# Exiftools not installing on Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, deployment, exiftool

I am trying to deploy my first project on Heroku and having an issue trying to install Exiftools on Heroku. My site is highly dependent on using `ExifField` within my models to get image information from pictures which is then displayed within my Django Admin to be edited etc. This all works fine locally in development.

`Exiffield` relies on Exiftool.exe to work, so I have to install a buildpack to Heroku which I have done, but it fails to see it during release when pushing to Heroku via CLI. All Django modules have installed OK.

I have added `Procfile` , `requirements`, `runtime` and everything seems to go OK, it even states it's intalled Exiftool but fails on release. Log below. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I was thinking it was issue with Procfile but it seems correct.

```
release: python manage.py migrate
   web: gunicorn blog.wsgi
```

```
Enumerating objects: 7, done.
Counting objects: 100% (7/7), done.
Delta compression using up to 16 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 375 bytes | 375.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 4 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
remote: -----> Using buildpacks:
remote:        1. heroku/python
remote:        2. https://github.com/benalavi/buildpack-exiftool
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> Using Python version specified in runtime.txt
remote:  !     Python has released a security update! Please consider upgrading to python-3.9.10
remote:        Learn More: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes
remote: -----> No change in requirements detected, installing from cache
remote: -----> Using cached install of python-3.9.0
remote: -----> Installing pip 21.3.1, setuptools 57.5.0 and wheel 0.37.0
remote: -----> Installing SQLite3
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
remote: -----> Skipping Django collectstatic since the env var DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC is set.
remote: -----> exiftool app detected
remote: -----> Installing exiftool-9.40
remote:        Setting PATH
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types -> release, web
remote:
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:        Done: 80.4M
remote: -----> Launching...
remote:  !     Release command declared: this new release will not be available until the command succeeds.
remote:        Released v37
remote:        https://********.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy... done.
remote: Running release command...
remote:
remote: SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:
remote:
remote: ERRORS:
remote: myblog.Photo.exif: (exiffield.E001) `exiftool` not found.
remote:         HINT: Please install `exiftool.`
remote: Waiting for release... failed.
To https://git.heroku.com/******.git
   7281f6e..bf1bc47  master -> master
```

Comment: Note that you only need to indent _or_ fence code blocks. If you do both you'll get unexpected results.

Comment: Is it in your requirements.txt?

Comment: I don't think this is relevant, but normally your main buildpack (Python in this case) [should be _last_](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-multiple-buildpacks-for-an-app#adding-a-buildpack), not first. **Edit:** Actually, maybe that _is_ relevant. Depending how `PATH` gets set, your Python code might not see the new value yet. Try reordering your buildpacks.

Comment: @KovyJacob, that's not relevant here. Libraries are being installed just fine. And `exiftool` is not installable via `pip`, hence the second buildpack OP is using.

Comment: @Chris Just wondering cuz it says Installing exiftool-9.40, thought the - is a bit sus

Comment: I didn't think it would be needed in requirements, django-exiffield==3.0.0, is indeed included, though.

Comment: I swapped the buildpacks over and still the same result. I'm stumped.